# /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:107: undefined reference to ***

Tags: linux, cmake, g++, gnu-make, boringssl

Running into errors when compiling Google's BoringSSL for NGINX QUIC on my Raspberry Pi 4B, with Raspberry Pi OS, aka Raspbian buster running on it.

### The commands I used to compile

As what [Google's document](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md) says, I used these commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
```

I've also tried to run `cmake` without passing `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`.

### Error output

Here's part of the error message. I'm not showing the entire output since it's too long (there are 352 lines). Tell me if the entire output is needed to solve this issue.

```
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable crypto_test
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/crypto_test.dir/abi_self_test.cc.o: in function `ABITest_SanityCheck_Test::TestBody()':
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unique_ptr.h:81: undefined reference to `abi_test_trampoline'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/crypto_test.dir/abi_self_test.cc.o: in function `ABITest_ARM_Test::TestBody()':
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:107: undefined reference to `abi_test_clobber_r4'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:107: undefined reference to `abi_test_trampoline'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:107: undefined reference to `abi_test_clobber_r0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:107: undefined reference to `abi_test_clobber_r1'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:107: undefined reference to `abi_test_clobber_r2'

......
```

### Additional information

```
cmake version 3.16.3
GNU Make 4.2.1

$ uname -a
Linux Kaibins-RPi 5.10.52-v8+ #1439 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 22 15:43:49 BST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Searched Google but I can't find any similar cases. I need help. Thanks so much.

> This issue can also be found in Chromium bug tracker：https://crbug.com/boringssl/422. You can find full error output in the attachment there.

Comment: Their bug tracker is [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/boringssl/issues/list).

Comment: The fact that the errors are coming from STL headers is a red herring, I believe.  The real problem is that the `abi_test_trampoline` class/struct, being used with **std::unique_ptr**, is not defined.  That's a problem in the code you're trying to compile, or in its configuration, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [boringssl package for OpenWrt](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/pull/15822) which supports BCM2711 boards (the one the Raspberry Pi 4B is using). There is even a [draft PR to package nginx with QUIC support](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/pull/16052). So, in principal, BoringSSL and nginx-quic work on this architecture. The BoringSSL version used in OpenWrt is from [June 2021](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/1f54fd9864c054dc33e15b1144e2a6a19fa0a52e).

I have also compiled BoringSSL on Raspberry Pi OS without issues. These are the steps I documented for compiling on Debian and, **from my memory, the same worked on Raspberry Pi OS:**

```
sudo apt install cmake libpcre3-dev golang mercurial
git clone https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl && cd boringssl
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j16
cd ../..
hg clone -b quic https://hg.nginx.org/nginx-quic && cd nginx-quic
./auto/configure --with-debug --with-http_v3_module --with-cc-opt="-I../boringssl/include" --with-ld-opt="-L../boringssl/build/ssl -L../boringssl/build/crypto"
make -j16
sudo cp objs/nginx /usr/bin/nginx-quic
```

I can try to verify this again with a newer version if I find some time.